# Does MH method works for you?

Tags: r

I am doing a meta-analysis.

I was working in a binary set of date of mine with this code :

```
#https://cran.r-project.org/package=meta
library(meta)

m.bin <- metabin(event.e = event.e, 
                n.e = n.e,
                event.c = event.c,
                n.c = n.c,
                studlab = study,
                data = data,
                method = "MH",
                sm = "RR",
                MH.exact = TRUE,
                fixed = FALSE,
                random = TRUE,
                method.tau = "PM",
                hakn = TRUE,
                title = "data")
summary(m.bin)
```

And what i get as a result il a IV method instead of MH
I just updated to meta 6.5

> Details on meta-analytical method:
> Inverse variance method
> Paule-Mandel estimator for tau^2
> Q-Profile method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
> Hartung-Knapp adjustment for random effects model (df = 38)

I tried changing method with IV (same results as MH method; I guess MH does not work anymore). I tried getting OR with Peto, it works

Comment: Welcome to SO, wingsteels! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.